Saving selected Outlook emails fails randomly
I used this code for several years to export a selection of emails from Outlook.
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objItem As Object
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

   For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Err.Clear
    If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Set oMail = objItem

        sName = oMail.Subject
        ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

        dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
        sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
                vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

        sPath = "D:\Data\ml\"
        Debug.Print sPath & sName
        oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG  
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub

Now it stops after exporting a random number of msg files. I think there is an error that is causing it to exit. Therefore I changed it as follows (Not the error handler):
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
  On Error GoTo ErrorContinue
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objItem As Object
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

   For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Err.Clear
    If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Set oMail = objItem

        sName = oMail.Subject
        ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

        dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
        sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
                vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

        sPath = "D:\Data\ml\"
        Debug.Print sPath & sName
        oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
ErrorContinue:
    Resume Next
    
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub

Version is 2308 (Build 16731.20504 Click-To-Run).
If I restart where it failed, that email exports. It doesn't seem to be anything particular with any email.
If I remove the error resume, the usual Debug option doesn't show up in the pop-up. Just has the buttons "OK" and "Help".


Is this a recent problem? There is currently an Outlook server problem that's causing mayhem with downloading embedded images and attachments (and possibly other things). You might find that the problem just 'disappears'. Blame Microsoft.

have you updated your Outlook? 32 or 64bit

Do you know which line of your code throws the exception?

@TangentiallyPerpendicular - Last year same code saved a whole years worth of email without any failure

@0m3r - I am sure its updated. Version is 2308 (Build 16731.20504 Click-To-Run). But it exports several emails fine. If I restart where it failed with the previous run, that email exports fine. So it doesnt seem to be anything particular with any email itself

@DmitryStreblechenko - Thats the problem. I cant tell since the usual Debug option doesnt show up in the pop-up. Just has the buttons "OK" and "Help" :(

try reversed loop, could be something getting modified or removed from the selection items

See if slowing the loop Pause Outlook for a given amount of time has an impact.

Consider deleting all the error handling. On Error Resume Next is useful in rare cases. Otherwise it is detrimental as it hides errors so they cannot be addressed.

Whatever the cause, this should handle any error on
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg_ErrorWithoutDebugDialog()
    
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sPathName As String
    
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim retryFlag As Boolean
    
    Dim selItems As selection
    
    Dim errNum As Long
    Dim errDesc As String
    
retry:
    
    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.selection
    Debug.Print "selItems.count: " & selItems.count
            
    retryFlag = False
    
    For i = selItems.count To 1 Step -1
    
        If selItems(i).MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
                
            Set oMail = selItems(i)
            sName = oMail.Subject
            ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
                
            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & _
                    Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & _
                    "-" & sName & ".msg"
                
            sPath = "D:\Data\ml\"
            
            ' This error would generate the usual debug dialog.
            'sPath = sPath & "NoFolder\"        ' To test the bypass
            Debug.Print sPath
            
            sPathName = sPath & sName
            Debug.Print sPathName
            
            ' Applicable in rare circumstances, when the error is known and expected.
            On Error Resume Next
            oMail.SaveAs sPathName, olMsg
                        
            ' Risky extra lines in the error bypass.
            errNum = Err.Number
            errDesc = Err.Description
                        
            '  Remove error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
            On Error GoTo 0
                        
            Debug.Print " errNum.: " & errNum
            Debug.Print " errDesc: " & errDesc
                        
            If errDesc = "" Then
                ' Success
                ActiveExplorer.RemoveFromSelection oMail
                DoEvents
                Debug.Print " Success. Item removed from selection."
                                
            Else
                ' Failure
                retryFlag = True
                Debug.Print " Failure. Item remains selected."
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    If retryFlag = True Then
        If MsgBox("Retry", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            GoTo retry
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub


Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, sChr As String)
    sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub

